# Windows Batch Scripting: Parse CSV file and extract data

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to windows batch scripting so pardon my ignorance. I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
01/02/2015,ABC,111
01/03/2015,DEF,222
01/03/2015,HHH,333
01/05/2015,XYZ,767
```

The number of rows in this file will vary but the columns will remain the same. I need to extract the date column A, row 1 and date from column A, last row.

In this case I need to extract 01/02/2015 and 01/05/2015. Next I want to store both these dates in separate variable.

How can I achieve this? I have no idea where to begin. The only thing I have is this:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%s in (IntFlow.csv) do @echo %%s
```

This one line of code cuts the first column and echo's it. I don't know what do next. Please advice.

Comment: The first tip is that Powershell or any scripting engine other than batch is much better suited and easier to learn for things like this than batch scripting.

Comment: @rojo You raise a valid point. I have edited the example file to comma delimited.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Point taken. I have switched to PowerShell ISE. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to parse the csv file line-by-line.  Use `skip=1` to skip the header row.  Only set the first variable if it isn't already defined.  Then just set the last variable on every loop iteration.  It's bound to be correct sooner or later, right?  :)

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "first="
set "last="

for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=," %%I in ("test.csv") do (
    if not defined first set "first=%%~I"
    set "last=%%~I"
)

echo %first%
echo %last%
```

`tokens=1` is already the default behavior.  `usebackq` allows you to enclose the filename in quotes, so it should work if your csv filename includes a space or some other unsavory character in the name.

---

I see in your comment you've decided to use PowerShell instead.  Here's a PowerShell script that'll let you populate variables with the dates.

```js
$csv = ipcsv test.csv
$first = ($csv | select -first 1 | %{ $_.ColumnA })
$last = ($csv | select -last 1 | %{ $_.ColumnA })

$first
$last
```

Comment: your code works but it extracts the entire row. What I want to do is just take the date part from column A. Given the sample file above, the output should like this:

01/02/2015

01/05/2015

Comment: I decided to switch back to batch. I am using APEX data loader and it can only ready bat files. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Does the entire row shown include commas?  Or are the values space-delimited?

Comment: Yes. It does include commas.

Comment: Unable to recreate.  The code as I have it in my answer parses the csv as you have in your question and outputs only the first and last `ColumnA` values.

Comment: it works! maybe I copied it wrong or something. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have a minor adjustment and I was wondering if you can help me out? The value in Column A is 3/30/2015 0:00 instead of just the date. I only need the date part. is there a way you can modify your script to cut only the date part from column A?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the values in Column A are not quoted, you could simply remove `delims=,` from the `for /f` attributes.